# Não inserir valor duplicado no gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Tenho uma função JavaScript que consigo inserir e deletar um item no Gridview, mas tenho enfrentado um problema ao não deixar que seja inserido um valor igual, pois não posso inserir um valor igual `dsEspecialidade` e nem deixar que existam dois `lgPresrPrincipal` marcados como "SIM".

```
function AdicionaEspecialidade() {


var dsEspecialidade = $("#Especialidade").val();
var lgPrestPrincipal = $("input[name='lgPrestPrincipal']:checked").val();


var Especialidade = {};
Especialidade.dsEspecialidade = dsEspecialidade;
Especialidade.lgPrestPrincipal = lgPrestPrincipal;


listaEspecialidades.push(Especialidade);
MontaGridEspecialidade();

return false;

}



(function ($) {
    remove = function (item, dsEspecialidade) {
        debugger;
        var especialidades = _.filter(listaEspecialidades, function (el) { return el.dsEspecialidade != dsEspecialidade });
        listaEspecialidades = especialidades;
        var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
        tr.fadeOut(400, function () { tr.remove(); });
        return false;
    }
})(jQuery);

function MontaGridEspecialidade() {
    $("#tbEspecialidades").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < listaEspecialidades.length; i++) {
        var HTML = '<tr>';
        HTML += '<td>' + listaEspecialidades[i].dsEspecialidade + '</td>';
        HTML += '<td>' + listaEspecialidades[i].lgPrestPrincipal + '</td>';
        HTML += '<td>';
        HTML += '<img id="btnApagaEspecialidade" src="App_Lib/Img/icoExcluir.gif" title="Apaga Especialidade" onclick="remove(this,\'' + listaEspecialidades[i].dsEspecialidade + '\')" />';
        HTML += '</td>';
        HTML += '</tr>';
        $("#tbEspecialidades").append(HTML);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só condicionar a inserção de uma nova entrada na array com `if` verificando se já existe um objeto com uma chave de mesmo valor e se já existe um objeto com valor "sim" ou se o valor for "não".

Para isso utilize o método `.find()` que busca na array um objeto onde o valor de `dsEspecialidade` é igual ao valor do input. Se não existir será inserido uma nova entrada, desde que o valor de `lgPrestPrincipal` não seja "sim" e já exista uma entrada com "sim" na array.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var listaEspecialidades = [];
function AdicionaEspecialidade() {

   var dsEspecialidade = $("#Especialidade").val();
   var lgPrestPrincipal = $("input[name='lgPrestPrincipal']:checked").val();
   
   // faz a verificação
   if(
      // verifica se não existe um objeto com o mesmo dsEspecialidade digitado no campo
      !listaEspecialidades.find(function(a){ return a.dsEspecialidade == dsEspecialidade })
      &&
      (
         // se o valor do campo for "sim" e não exista um objeto com "sim"
         lgPrestPrincipal == "sim" && !listaEspecialidades.find(function(a){ return a.lgPrestPrincipal == "sim" })
         ||
         lgPrestPrincipal == "nao"
      )
   ){
      var Especialidade = {};
      Especialidade.dsEspecialidade = dsEspecialidade;
      Especialidade.lgPrestPrincipal = lgPrestPrincipal;
      
      listaEspecialidades.push(Especialidade);
      MontaGridEspecialidade();
   }
   
   return false;
}

(function ($) { remove = function (item, dsEspecialidade) { debugger; var especialidades = _.filter(listaEspecialidades, function (el) { return el.dsEspecialidade != dsEspecialidade }); listaEspecialidades = especialidades; var tr = $(item).closest('tr'); tr.fadeOut(400, function () { tr.remove(); }); return false; } })(jQuery);

function MontaGridEspecialidade() {
    $("#tbEspecialidades").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < listaEspecialidades.length; i++) {
        var HTML = '<tr>';
        HTML += '<td>' + listaEspecialidades[i].dsEspecialidade + '</td>';
        HTML += '<td>' + listaEspecialidades[i].lgPrestPrincipal + '</td>';
        HTML += '<td>';
        HTML += '<img id="btnApagaEspecialidade" src="App_Lib/Img/icoExcluir.gif" title="Apaga Especialidade" onclick="remove(this,\'' + listaEspecialidades[i].dsEspecialidade + '\')" />';
        HTML += '</td>';
        HTML += '</tr>';
        $("#tbEspecialidades").append(HTML);
    }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Especialidade">
<input type="radio" name="lgPrestPrincipal" value="sim" checked> SIM
<input type="radio" name="lgPrestPrincipal" value="nao"> NÃO
<button onclick="AdicionaEspecialidade()">Adicionar</button>
<table border="1" id="tbEspecialidades"></table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, funcionou (y).